# Android only rotate certain views in Tabs

Tags: android, xml, rotation, android-manifest, tabcontrol

I want to only allow landscape rotations on some of my views, the problem is that all of my activities are loaded within a tab controller that has rotation disabled.

I have one tab controller that loads views of all my other activities. In my manifests file I have that activity set to

```
 android:screenOrientation="portrait"
 android:label="@string/app_name"
 android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
```

now, although all of my other activities say the same thing, if I simple removed the `screenOrientation` field from the main tabloading activity, then all of the other views would be subject to screen rotations

how do I make this happen more selectively, is there a programmatic way to override this the manifest parameters via conditional statements?